# Angular 2 - How does the directive give data to the host?

Tags: typescript, angular

I have what I think should be a pretty simply problem to solve in Angular 2, but I just can't find the right syntax.

My goal is a directive that does the following:

1. Accepts arbitrary data as value. E.g., `[my-data]="[1,2,3,4,5]"`
2. Processes this on change. E.g. `onChange() { return this.data.length = 55; }`.
3. Sends this data to the host, and binds to a host property.

I'm fine on 1), but a little lost on 2) and 3). So far I have something like:

```
@Directive({
  selector: ['ap-data'],
  host: {
    '(change)': 'onChange()'
  }
})
export class DataDirective {

  @Input('ap-data') data: any;

  @HostBinding('attr.ap-data') get dataSet() {
    return processData(this.data);
  }

  ...

}

@Component({
  selector: 'myComponent',
  directive: [DataDirective],
  template: `
   <div [ap-data]="[1,2,3,4,5]"></div>
  `
})
export class MyComponent {

  public data: any[];

  public dataSet: ProcessedDataType;

  ...

}
```

Comment: Your selector for `DataDirective` should be `selector: ['[ap-data]']` by using `selector: ['ap-data']` angular is looking for a tag `<ap-data>`

Comment: Late-night typo but thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For directive to host binding use an `EventEmitter`:

```
@Output('ap-data-change') apDataChange: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter() 

onChange() {
  ... 
  this.apDataChange.next(someValue);
} 

<div [ap-data]="[1,2,3,4,5]" (ap-data-change)=hostField=event$></div>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, could this be done with HostBindings? Docs say (I believe) hostbidings monitor property value changes and update the host element. I'm not sure what is meant by "update the host element" beyond setting a css class.

Comment: "host" in case of host-binding is the tag in HTML of the component or directive, not the parent element. `@HostBinding('class.my-class') myClass: bool = true;` in `DataDirective` would result in `<div [ap-data] ... class="my-class">`